# REST call may results in two different JSON objects. What design pattern should I use?

Tags: parsing, rest, design-patterns

My web application makes a REST call. If the call is successful, it will return a 'weather' json object. If the call fails, it will return a json error object.

I want to make a class that parses the resulting JSON and returns a `Weather` object if the call succeeded and an `Error` Object if the call failed.

I'm thinking of using the Factory pattern but I'm not sure if that's a good approach because the two objects are very different from one another. What is a good way to design this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach I use is to have `Weather` and `Error` both be `Response` objects and have a `ResponseFactory` create them.

I strongly encourage you to use proper HTTP codes when designing your service as they give a more general view of the state and success of each call.

Comment: The problem is that the Weather object is a Model class in my MVC Pattern. I think it's a bit messy if I'd make inherit from Response.

Comment: @W.K.S, that is surely a problem. This is an implementation problem though - the original question didn't specify that there was Model or Response implementations already. Some of the work I do put the errors in a log (db) - and thereby justify that the Error object is also Model objects.

Comment: I'm thinking of making a `WeatherException` class (I'll come up with a better name later) that contains all the error codes and messages. So the `WeatherFactory` will create `Weather` Objects if the code succeeds but it'll create and throw a `WeatherException` if the code fails. Does that still conform with the Factory Pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You need first to check the result of the call, and then make a decision on how to handle it, with the possibility of handling all error codes with an error callback that returns an `Error` JSON object, and a success callback to return a `Weather` JSON object. You can use the HTTP codes to create a proper response and further subdivide the logic to return more specific errors, if needed.

The use of a Factory pattern seems overkill, specially given that the objects don't relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the environment you'll be using your API.

As a rule of thumb, rely on the HTTP code - if you get a 404 or a 500 of course you can't come up with a parsed response.

Format your error responses in a consistent way, e.g.

```
404 { "message" : "Resource not found" }
400 { "message" : "Wrong parameters given" }
```

So you know how to parse them.

If you get a `200 OK`you know everything was right, and you can parse your response with no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Content-Type` header vary depending on the type of response?

As some have noted in their answers, the HTTP status code should be used to determine "Was there an error", but just as important is the interpretation of the content type returned.

Hoping the `Content-Type` header does vary, I would suggest using a registry of parsers, registered by content-type they handle, and then delegate to them to handle understanding how to convert a particular content type into the object you want. In Ruby, since you didn't specify a particular language:

```
case response.status:
  when 200..299
    return parsers[response.content_type].parse(response.body)
  when 400..499
    raise parsers[response.content_type].parse(response.body)
  else
    raise "Unhandled response status"
```

Doing so separates the two concerns:

- Determining if there was an error
- Parsing of content types into classes/types in your application.